# Why does the simulator not display my google button until I stop running it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-signin

I have followed through [Google's tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift) to integrate their sign-in button in my new iOS project, but the sign-in button doesn't display when I build. Oddly enough, it only shows when I stop running and open the app on the simulator myself. It seems very strange, and I have a really hard time debugging this issue because I'm a total beginner in swift(and honestly find it a tad bit confusing as a newbie).

I have pretty much copy pasted their code in my project(and added my clientID where needed) and followed through every one of their steps. The button works fine when the simulator stops running. Does it have to do anything with Main.storyboard vs LaunchScreen.storyboard(my button is in Main)? What am I missing here?

Here is my ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().presentingViewController = self

        // Automatically sign in the user.
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().restorePreviousSignIn()

    }

    @IBAction func didTapSignOut(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
    }
}
```

And this is what I added in the beginning of AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "My client ID"
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    return true
}

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
  return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
  return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!)
{
    if let error = error
    {
        if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue
        {
            print("The user has not signed in before or they have since signed out.")
        }
        else
        {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return
    }
    // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
    let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
    let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
    let fullName = user.profile.name
    let givenName = user.profile.givenName
    let familyName = user.profile.familyName
    let email = user.profile.email
    // ...
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {
  // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
  // ...
}
```

Thank you

Comment: There is no error. The button simply does not show up on the simulator screen until I stop running the simulator(but not exiting the simulator). When the simulator has stopped running, I reopen the app via the simulator and that's when the button is visible. I used the same code as Google's tutorial. Went through it a couple of times.

Comment: Please share the code.. even though you copy and pasted it its easier to debug if we can see it all. specifically share your viewDidLoad()

Comment: Alright, I shared the code. Also, in my Main storyboard, the button is a View with 'GIDSignInButton' as custom class